# using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4, asihttprequest

I wonder if any one could help me with the issue of HOW TO KEEP INAPP PURCHASE DOWNLOADING WHEN THE DEVICE GOES TO SLEEP MODE USING ASIHTTPREQUEST, i did an application that contains some music files to be purchased and downloaded in the app, but if the user purchases and start downloading the album for example, if his phone sleeps,its stops downloading!!!
Appreciate any comments with regards,

```
-(void) downloadAlbum:(NSNumber *)Albumid {
//NSLog(@"%@",Albumid);
//myTable.scrollEnabled = NO;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];

if (CurrentSongID<=CurrentAlbumCount) {
    if (isDownload==FALSE) {    

        Reachability* internetReach = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
        [internetReach startNotifier];
        NetworkStatus netStatus = [internetReach currentReachabilityStatus];

        switch (netStatus)
        {
            case NotReachable:
            {   UIAlertView *someError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Top 10" message: @"Check Internet Connectivity" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [someError show];
                [someError release];
                break;
            }

            case ReachableViaWWAN:
            {   
            }
            case ReachableViaWiFi:

            {   NSString *DestinationFileName= [self FileNameGetter:Albumid FileID:CurrentSongID ];
                NSString * URL=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://core-4.doubleu.mobi/cdownload/%@/%d.mp3",[self AlbumNameGetter:Albumid],CurrentSongID];

                isDownload=TRUE;
                progressIndicator.hidden=FALSE;
                DownloadedFileName.hidden=FALSE;
                NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Albums" ofType:@"plist"];
                contentArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
                //NSLog(@"%@",contentArray);
                DownloadedFileName.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d",CurrentSongID ,CurrentAlbumCount];//[CurrentAlbum count]];
                if (!networkQueue) {
                    networkQueue = [[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init];  
                }
                failed = NO;
                [networkQueue setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressIndicator];
                [networkQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(nextDownload)];
                [networkQueue setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
                [networkQueue setDelegate:self];
                request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
                [request setDownloadDestinationPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Caches"] 
                                                     stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3",[self FileNameGetter:Albumid FileID:CurrentSongID ]]]];

                [networkQueue addOperation:request];
                [networkQueue go];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *someError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Top 10" message: @"Please wait Until download Completed" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [someError show];
        [someError release];
    }

}
else {
    //NSString *DestinationFileName= [self FileNameGetter:NSCurrentAlbumID FileID:CurrentSongID ];
    //myTable.scrollEnabled = YES;

    switch (CurrentAlbumIDd) {
            //to be modified
        case 1:
        {
            //NSString *DestinationFileName= [self FileNameGetter:NSCurrentAlbumID FileID:CurrentSongID ];
            UIAlertView *someError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"فضل شاكر" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Download بياع القلوب Completed"] delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [someError show];
            [someError release];
            //[Album1 setTag:Album1.tag*100];
            downloaded1 = TRUE;
            available1=1;

            break;}
        case 2:
        {
            UIAlertView *someError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"فضل شاكر" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Download الحب القديم Completed"] delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [someError show];
            [someError release];
        //  [Album2 setTag:Album2.tag*100];
            downloaded2 = TRUE;
            available2=1;
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            UIAlertView *someError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"فضل شاكر" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Download حبك خيال Completed"] delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [someError show];
            [someError release];
        //  [Album3 setTag:Album3.tag*100];
            downloaded3 = TRUE;
            available3=1;
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all needed infos on the [How To Use Page](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) from the [ASIHTTPRequest Doku](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

1. [Resuming downloads](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#resuming_interrupted_downloads)
2. [Download in Background](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#background_downloads_ios)

set the `setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES` to your request

```
 request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
 [request setDownloadDestinationPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Caches"] 
                                                 stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3",[self FileNameGetter:Albumid FileID:CurrentSongID ]]]];
[request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
```

Comment: how can i add the method [request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];??? which class should i add to make this method available??

Comment: dude the method "setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground" is not listed as u mentioned above!!! whats wrong??

Comment: come on, its in the Docu an its in the ASIHTTPRequest class...!